# Review test question possible bug?

Tags: bug

Today I did First post review and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13457858) question. I may be wrong, but I believe recently there was a time, when I tried to **open** reviewed question in a **new tab** (by clicking on Q header). And I saw that question and it really looked like it is present on the site. By successfully passing that test, I was told that this question was closed or deleted and I was no longer be able to view that question.

But today I clicked on header and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684859/doing-a-monte-carlo-simulation-with-a-specific-distribution) page. So now it was **obvious** for me, that this is a test.

I know that this also proves that I'm paying attention, but if I'm right about "pretending" functionality, this could be bug.

And if I'm wrong, I'm sorry for bothering you.

**EDIT:**
I'm aware about marked question, but this is not that case. I'm saying that the another day I opened the question and it was modified (just for the time I was doing the review). Today I opened that question and I saw (more or less http 404). So I'd expect to see that question like the other day (and just only for the time of my review)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking. Are you saying that the first time you opened the question in a new tab, it showed up as if it had not been deleted?

Comment: @CodyGray basically saying yes, but with another question. Unfortunatelly I'm not sure about it - maybe it was only modified *good* question with many upvotes and well rated answers, which looked like first post (like 0 ups, asked the day before etc.). But I'm definitelly sure that i met some kind of "pretending" functionality.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich If you click the link to go see the question on the site, outside of review, you're going to see the actual question. A question used for an audit is disguised *in* review but there's no function to disguise questions *outside* of review.

Comment: Audits are meant to catch people who don't pay attention.  By the fact that you caught the audit, you have shown that you are paying attention.  The type of people who are meant to fail the audit are those who would have simply clicked "looks ok" rather than spend the time to examine the post outside of the review page.